# Why does my QStandardItemModel itemFromIndex method return None? (index invalid)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I am trying to make a listview with checkboxes that checks the selected boxes when the **enter/return key** is pressed. I do this with an override of the eventfilter for my MainWindow (yes I ought to subclass it, but I couldn't get that working)

In the eventfilter i get a **None** value returned from the **itemFromIndex** method even though I just passed the index through a **.isValid()** without problems. Obviously i am missing something, but i can't figure it out - is it looking at completely different indices? is the model not updated?

Any advice on alternate approaches are welcome

This is the method I use to fill the model (**QStandardItemModel**) with items, it's only called when i load a file.

```
    def update_siNLV(self,names,model):

        model.clear()

        for name in names:            
            item = Qg.QStandardItem(name)
            item.setCheckState(Qc.Qt.Unchecked)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            model.appendRow(item)
```

This is from the **init** method where I create a variable for the selectionmodel and install the eventfilter on my **QListView**

```
    self.sigInSelection = self.siNLV.selectionModel()
    self.siNLV.installEventFilter(self)
```

The **eventFilter** method looks like this and the filtering part of the method works (I've made it print the selected indices with press on the enter key)

```
    def eventFilter(self,receiver,event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return or event.key() == Qc.Qt.Key_Enter:

                indexes = self.sigInSelection.selectedIndexes()

                for index in indexes:
                    if index.isValid():                        
                        print(str(index.row())+" "+str(index.column()))                                   
                        item = self.sigInModel.itemFromIndex(index)
                        item.setCheckState(qtCore.Qt.Checked)                     
                return True

    return super(form,self).eventFilter(receiver,event)
```

Comment: You appear to have checked that `index` is a valid index in `sigInSelection` - there is no *a priori* reason it should also be a valid index in `sigInModel`.

Comment: you're right. So even though the `sigInModel` is set to the listview it doesn't share indexes with the `siNLV` built-in selectionmodel? Then how would i couple the selections to my data?

Comment: I can't see where you call `itemFromIndex` without success since you say the `eventFilter` works.  We probably need to see a bit more code.  An MVCE might help.

Comment: I've edited the question to clear misunderstandings. it's the `itemFromIndex` part of the eventfilter that doesn't work

Comment: The only important data in the `index` here is the row and column you are already printing and the `index.model()`.  Check that that does have the value you expect (i.e. it should equal the `sigInModel`).  If those three values are all correct then the `itemFromindex` should work.

Comment: I can't seem the get a hold of the actual model returned, but the type is a `QSortFilterProxyModel` which i guess makes sense since i applied one to the `siNLV` but completely forgot about it. I guess i have to use the `mapToSource` feature to get indexes of the itemmodel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

The indices returned by `QItemSelectionModel.selectedIndexes()` come from the view and relate to the connection between the view and its immediate model.  The identity of that model can be found by calling `QModelIndex.model()` and in this case it is not the model that you want: it is instead a proxy model that is in-between your desired `QStandardItemModel` and the view.

To get to the model you want you need to use `QAbstractProxyModel.mapToSource()`.  So you might use code something like this:

```
source_index = self.proxy.mapToSource(index)
item = self.sigInModel.itemFromIndex(source_index)
```

More generally you could traverse an arbitrary proxy structure and avoid this hard-coded usage of a single known proxy by code something like:

```
proxy_model = index.model()
while proxy_model != self.sigInModel:
    index = proxy_model.mapToSource(index)
    proxy_model = index.model()
item = self.sigInModel.itemFromIndex(index)
```

But this is probably overkill in this case where you know there is a simple single proxy.